# ajax is not reading json php response correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have done a lot of reading research on trying to figure out why ajax is reading a json response as undefined, and of course I have tried a lot of those solutions too, but unfortunately they don't work for me. If you guys can help, it would be GREAT!!!!

I have tried adding dataType: 'json', using data.status and data['status'], they still come as undefined. I can see see php responding the correct status in json format (an example of the response is at the bottom of the page)

php side:

```
//doing sql query
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  $response_array["status"] = "success";
} elseif ($conn->errno == 1062) {
  $response_array["status"] = "dup";
} else {
  $response_array["status"] = "error";  
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response_array);
```

jquery side:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#name_form').submit( function(event) {
        if ( !formValidation()) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            var datastr = $('#addclass_form').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: someurl,
                data: datastr,
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data.status);
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('php error');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

html side:

```
<form id='name_form'>
    <div>
      <b>Class Name</b>
      <input type='text' name='classname' id='classname' placeholder='Enter Class Name'>
    </div>
    <div class='ui-grid-c'>
      <div class='ui-block-a main'><b>Component</b></div>
      <div class='ui-block-b point'><b>Max Point</b></div>
      <div class='ui-block-c per'><b>Percentage</b></div>
    </div>
    <div id='components'>
      <div class='ui-grid-c'>
        <div class='ui-block-a main'><input type='text' name='component0' id='component0' placeholder='Component'></div>
        <div class='ui-block-b point'><input type='number' name='point0' id='point0' placeholder='Max Point'></div>
        <div class='ui-block-c per'><input type='number' name='percentage0' id='percentage0' placeholder='Percentage'></div>
      <div class='ui-block-d rm'><button type='button' class='ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext' disabled></button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type='hidden' name='compSize' id='compSize'>
    <input type='submit' class='ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-shadow ui-corner-all' value='Create Class'>
  </form>
```

output of console.log(data):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    {"status":"success"}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use this in response $.parseJSON()

Comment: success: function(data) {
                   data = $.parseJSON(data);
                    console.log(data.status);
                }

Comment: I got an unexpected token error for parseJSON, I think that didn't work mainly because data wasn't a string in json format.

Comment: From the console log you've posted, you're not returning JSON, but HTML

Comment: are you including header in " addclass_confirmation.php " File ?

Comment: that's what I have noticed too, do you know how I can go about correcting that, I assume the correction should on the php side?

Comment: I didn't include any header, but I thought this line of php code would have taken care of it.  header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: The problem is on the server side. It seems that before you are outputting your json (`echo json_encode($response_array);`), there is some code that echoes HTML. All that `<!doctype html>` and other HTML stuff shouldn't be in your response in order for JS to parse JSON correctly.

Comment: Set dataType: 'json' in  your AJAX request

Comment: yup getting rid of all the other html tags did the trick! Thanks @VictorMarchuk